# Connect my API to HTML with J.Query/Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

After I have been trying to make up a good JSON java API I finally made it. I have used a pretty simple API which looks like this (Took a example of Interstellar) :

```
    {
    "title": "Interstellar",
    "release": "2014-11-05",
    "vote": 8,
    "overview": "Interstellar chronicles the adventures of a group of explorers who make use of a newly discovered wormhole to surpass the limitations on human space travel and conquer the vast distances involved in an interstellar voyage.",
    "poster": "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/nBNZadXqJSdt05SHLqgT0HuC5Gm.jpg",
    "trailer": "https://youtu.be/zSWdZVtXT7E"
}
```

so I started to make a really simple HTML (I'm really new at this and just want to make it work as beginning and then I can develop it better in the future)

So it looks like this right now

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Movies</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center><div id="tfheader">
        <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="Search movie">
                <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="q" size="15" maxlength="120"><input type="submit" value="search" class="tfbutton">
        </form>
    <div class="tfclear"></div></center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

where I have only a search button right now which doesn't do anything. so my idea is to make, when I search for a movie example Interstellar. It should pop out things that I have in my JSON into the HTMl, Which I mean like title, overview and so on. but I don't really know how to start. I started by this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "",
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}
  })
```

and now i'm stuck, basically all I want to do is when I search in the search bar in the HTML, it should "connect" to my API and the API gives the information back and then it should pop out in my HTML site. (It doesn't even have to look good as a start) so my question is, how can I make the 'magic' happened?

Comment: You need to move your ajax calls to an the button click event

Comment: Could you explain or give me an example how to do it? I'm really new at HTML and never done this before, Would really appreciate the time you taking for me aswell!

Comment: Ill add an answer mate give me 2  mins...

Comment: Ok, Sir :) @AdamJeffers

Comment: I looked at AdamJeffers answer. He's got you going down the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your markup was a little wrong... here it is correct.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Movies</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <div id="tfheader">
            <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="Search movie">
                <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="q" size="15" maxlength="120"><input type="submit" value="search" class="tfbutton">
            </form>
            <div class="tfclear"></div>
        </div>
     </center>
</body>
</html>
```

And your JS should like this...

```
function callAjax()
{
    var url = "http://whatever.com"
    $.ajax({
        url: url,  
        success: function(data) 
        {
            $('.tfclear').append(data); 
        },
        error: function(err)
        {
            // throw error
        }
    });
}
```

And your button binding...

```
$('. tfbutton').on('click', function(){
     callAjax();
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you're doing it all inline should be like the below...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Movies</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function callAjax()
{
    var url = "http://localhost:1337/search/"
    $.ajax({
        url: url,  
        success: function(data) 
        {
            $('.tfclear').append(data); 
        },
        error: function(err)
        {
            // throw error
        }
    });
}

$('.tfbutton').on('click', function(){
     callAjax();
});
</script>

<body>
    <center>
        <div id="tfheader">
            <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="Search movie">
                <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="q" size="15" maxlength="120"><input type="submit" value="search" class="tfbutton">
            </form>
            <div class="tfclear"></div>
        </div>
     </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Im sorry if im wrong, I edited my post. Could you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Please check my latest update to my answer... I had some uppercase letters for "tfButton" class name etc

Comment: Okey so I changed it too, but there is no results when searching in  the search bar. I mean nothing pops out. it just stuck and the url changes only to search="movie title" and im my api it works like this: http://localhost:1337/search/"enter movie here". so I think I have to change the input ?

Comment: Silly question I suppose, but do you have any errors in your console? Like jQuery not loaded etc?

Comment: Hmm, There is right now only a search bar, When entering a movie title etc. Interstellar. and then pressing the button search button it just take me to a another site where it says website not found, ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: What file is not found?

Comment: Im not really sure, the problem I see is that the URL is turning to /Search?q=Interstellar at the end. Since I don't have a q=.... in my api, can that be something? Or maybe i'm thinking the wrong way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92970/discussion-between-adamjeffers-and-weinthis).